# statistics questions soldier

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation

$X$ denotes the height of soldiers that is normally distributed with $\mu = 68.22$ in and $\sigma = 10.8$ in$^2$. How many soldiers in a regiment of 1000 would you expect to be over 6 feet tall?

Comment: Can you show your effort?

Comment: Do you know how to compute a Z-score ?

Comment: It might be helpful to some people to note that 10.8 inches in feet is 0.9 feet

Answer (score 2):

Sq. in. *can't* be right for the population SD. (Squared units would be appropriate for a population variance, not for a population SD;  I wonder whether 10.8 sq.in. is a reasonable variance for soldiers.)

This is not a 'do your homework' site, so here is an outline for when you are ready to do the work:

If you mean $X \sim NORM(\mu=68.22, \sigma^2=10.8),$ then standardize to get $P(X > 72),$ using a normal table. Multiply by 1000. The answer I got rounds to about 125.

The probability you want is represented by the area under the curve and to
the right of the vertical red line.

[image]